# Python 3, concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor and CEF crashes after pool size is reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, chromium-embedded, concurrent.futures

I'm on Win 10 with Python 3.9.6 and am trying to create a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` pool with a small size and add a lot of tasks to it which use CEF.

This always works for the first tasks up until the pool size is reached and afterwards every future reports the exception

```
"A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending."
```

The problem only occurs when i'm shutting down CEF; it cannot be reproduced anymore when `cef.Shutdown()` is not called.

This is test testcode:

```
import sys
import concurrent.futures
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef

def tst():
    settings = { "windowless_rendering_enabled": True }
    try:
        cef.Initialize(settings=settings, switches={})
        cef.Shutdown()
    except:
        print("Unexpected error in tst:", sys.exc_info()[0])

def _main():
    futures = []
    try:
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            for i in range(4):
                futures.append(executor.submit(tst))
        for f in futures:
            print(f'{f._state} - {f.exception()}')
    except:
        print("Unexpected error in main:", sys.exc_info()[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

It's also [available online](https://godbolt.org/z/fWG9WY5T9) but i couldn't find an online python IDE which offers CEF.

The expected output is

```
FINISHED - None
FINISHED - None
FINISHED - None
```

but the actual output is

```
FINISHED - None
FINISHED - None
FINISHED - A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

Setting max_workers to 4 and the range to 6 would follow the pattern, resulting in 4 times "None" and 2 times the error.

For each failed task, the windows application log will list an error like

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.9.6150.1013, time stamp: 0x60d9eb23
Faulting module name: libcef.dll, version: 3.3359.1774.0, time stamp: 0x5afd9b5a
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x0000000001e83c58
Faulting application path: ...\Python39\python.exe
Faulting module path: ...\Python39\lib\site-packages\cefpython3\libcef.dll
```

I made a [second version of the test](https://godbolt.org/z/f4q5E694f) which tries to narrow down the position in the code where the crash occurs and it appears that it's right at `cef.Initialize`.

I'm a bit lost at the moment because i don't have much experience with Python and even less with CEF. Is it a problem with the concurrent package, or CEF, or are the two just not ment to work together nicely? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: For what it's worth, exception 0x80000003 in Windows is a debug breakpoint.  My guess is the library did an assert.

Comment: You might add `"debug": True` to the application settings to see if anything else is revealed.  I don't see anything obvious in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEF does not allow to call `Initialize` after calling `Shutdown`. See [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2090) for more info.

When you have more tasks than worker processes, those tasks are queued to be executed later  when a worker becomes available.

The first 2 tasks run ok, because a new process is created for each one of them.

The third task fails because it runs in a process that has already been used (i.e.: initialized).

A quick fix would be to add  a guard, for example:

```
initialized = False

def tst():
    global initialized
    settings = { "windowless_rendering_enabled": True }
    try:
        if not initialized:
            initialized = True
            cef.Initialize(settings=settings, switches={})

            # you cannot call shutdown now, sorry
            #cef.Shutdown()

        # do stuff...
    except:
        print("Unexpected error in tst:", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Remember: You are creating new processes, each one with their own memory space. Therefore, there will be absolutely no problem in using a global variable.

**Update:** If you want to call `cef.Shutdown()` you could do something like this (haven't tested it):

```
import signal

initialized = False

def tst():
    global initialized
    settings = { "windowless_rendering_enabled": True }
    try:
        if not initialized:
            def signal_handler(_, __):
                cef.Shutdown()
            signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
            signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
           
            cef.Initialize(settings=settings, switches={})
            initialized = True

        # do stuff...
    except:
        print("Unexpected error in tst:", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Comment: Oh, i see. Quite obvious after reading the issue you pointed to :) I need different settings and switches for each instance, so i guess i have to spawn or fork my own processes and don't use the pool.